# How do I sum values in a column using a table?

Tags: html, coldfusion

I have a table that i get values from a query,
I would want to get the total sum for every row.
I have try using if statements something like

```
 <cfif ECA GTE 0><td align="center">#ECA#</td>  <cfset totaleca+=ECA></CFIF>
```

but i dont get the correct sum.
How would I get the sum for all the columns?

I made a http://jsfiddle.net/w2k3y3kz/2/

CODE:

```
<table id="table-example-1"><caption>testing</caption>
   <thead><tr>
       <th colspan="1"></th>
       <th colspan="3">ECA</th>


    </tr><tr>

       <th></th>
       <th>open</th>



        </tr></thead>

<cfoutput query="getSubtotal">
    <cfset totaleca = 0>
<cfset totalsum = 0>
     </tr></thead><tbody><tr><td style="width:70px"; align="center">#numberformat(mid(getSubtotal.oaoperiod,5,2))#/#left(getSubtotal.oaoperiod,4)#  </td>
   <td align="center">#ECA#</td> 
     <td align="center">#ECAClose#</td> 
     <td align="center">#ECAcos#</td>   
    <td align="center">#NSA#</td>   
     <td align="center">#NSAClose#</td> 


    </tr>
    </tbody>

    </cfoutput>
    <cfoutput>
        <tfoot>


    <tr>
     <td></td>

    </tr>

      </cfoutput>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: So like output all the rows and then at the bottom have a row that is just the sums of those values in each column? Personally I'd do it in the query before outputting, but other than that I think you'll have to create variables and add to them. `totalECA += ECA should be working unless you have some strange grouping going on. Though I'm not sure why you need the if statement.

Comment: I do see one thing, you are setting the `totaleca = 0` in the output loop. Thus setting it to 0 with each loop. It needs to be before the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use array functions on query columns.  The equivalent command for this:

```
<cfif ECA GTE 0><td align="center">#ECA#</td>  <cfset totaleca+=ECA></CFIF>
```

is

```
<cfset totaleca = ArraySum(getSubtotal['eca'])>
```

If you want to add the totals of more than one column, do something like this:

```
<cfstet totalSum = ArraySum(getSubtotal['eca']) 
                        + ArraySum(getSubtotal['ecaclose']) 
                        etc ... >
```

Comment: `arraySum()` may have floating point rounding error so if you want to be careful, use your own loop with `PrecisionEvaluate()`

Answer (score 3):

I think you can refer to Ben Nadel's [this Blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/167-calling-array-functions-on-coldfusion-query-columns.htm) for applying different array functions on a query object.

Example: If query object contains two columns Name and Mark, we have to calculate sum of all marks then we can use: Arraysum( q['mark'] )

Similarly, we can also use other array functions like: ArrayMax(q['Mark']), ArrayMin(q['Mark']), ArrayAvg(q['mark'])

Comment: I dont know why but im just seeing this answer everytime i refresh i didnt see answer to the question , weird, anyways that exactly what i use , that post and i did this ,<cfset sumECA =Arraysum (getSubtotal["eca"]) />